# LiteDB Studio fail to connect LiteDB

Tags: litedb

I have a **encrypted** LiteDB, When i opened with LiteDB studio, without enter password, i got the following error.
[image]

after enter password, i got this error

[image]

Any expert can help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

ok, found the solution. LiteDB studio is supporting v5, my litedb is v4, i have to tick this before connect.

[image]